# Passive tense difference between with be form and without be form

Tags: passive-voice

What's the difference between these two sentences?
Ex1:

> information requested to be confirmed

> information which is/was requested to be confirmed

Please translate them into active voice
Thanks

Comment: _The government provided/provides  information_ for the second one. The first one isn't a complete sentence.

Comment: The second one isn't a sentence either.

Comment: Kindly confirm the information I requested. Another interpretation: I requested confirmation of the information.

Answer (score 1):

> information provided by the government

This is not a sentence, it is a noun phrase.

> Information was/is provided by the government.

This is a complete sentence. It starts with a capital letter and ends with a full-stop.

Answer (score 0):

When we say 'information provided by the government' we are talking about the nature of the information not the provision of it. That is we say things like "Read the information provided by the government". In this case the phrase 'provided by the government' is an *adjectival phrase* modifying 'information'.

On the other hand when we say 'information was provided by the government' we are talking about the way in which the information was provided, not about the nature of the information. That is we say things like "This information was provided by the government". In this case 'by the government' is an *adverbial phrase* modifying 'was provided'.

Comment: _by the government_ is a prepositional phrase functioning as an adverb. Isn't it?

Comment: @Pkjmm You're right, it is; but I had to look it up. I wasn't convinced that 'by' in "done by X' was still a preposition. However I would say the distinction between an adverbial phrase and a prepositional phrase acting as an adverb is less important than the difference I was trying to explain between the adjectival phrase and the adverbial function.